# A self hosted private social network for a few thousand members

Tags: social-networks

I am researching to find a suitable social network software for a private network of up to a few thousand members.

It should have:

- profiles
- private messages
- public and private groups/spaces
- an event calendar
- invite only membership

Nice to have would be:

- payment gateway for fees or donations
- question form for invited new members
- new member application form
- official (admin created) groups/spaces/events and member groups/spaces/events
- mobile app
- live video streaming

I am looking for experiences on the various options and how easy it is to run them on rather simple server hardware. And to get a feel how big a server I would need.

Options I looked at so far:

- https://moosocial.com/
- https://www.opensource-socialnetwork.org
- https://www.oxwall.com/
- https://www.humhub.com/
- https://www.getopensocial.com/
- https://www.joomlapolis.com/community-builder
- https://friendi.ca/
- https://una.io/
- https://elgg.org/
- https://scuttlebutt.nz/
- https://fediverse.party/

So far HumHub seems like a good balance of features, simplicity and ease of use to me.

Friendica looks also very interesting, but maybe a bit too complex.

Diaspora seemed too complex to run and too complicated for the potential users. And Mastodon seemed not to be the right platform either.

Any experiences or opinions anyone wants to share?

Is a VPS with 4 vCore and 16 GB RAM enough for the first 1k members / 100 concurrent users?

Comment: Another one to evaluate is [SocialEngine](https://www.socialengine.com/).